# Why is $\mathbb T\varphi$ called a "ray"?

Tags: terminology, hilbert-spaces, intuition

Let $\mathbb T$ be the set of all complex numbers of modulus 1 (i.e the unit circle on the complex plane). For any element $\varphi$ of the complex Hilbert space $H$, the set $\mathbb T\varphi$ is called a *ray* (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wigner%27s_theorem&oldid=914633231#Rays_and_ray_space)).

What is the intuition behind this name? Why a ray?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of this is that there are two equivalent philosophies to handle the state vector in quantum mechanics.

One philosophy is to *not* require the vector to be normalized. In that case, multiplying a state vector with an *arbitrary* non-zero complex number gives another vector representing the same state. The set $\{c\psi\mid c\in\mathbb C^\times\}$ is called a ray; the intuition is that it is similar to a ray in real vector spaces, defined as $\{\lambda v\mid \lambda\in\mathbb R_{>0}\}$.

However in that philosophy, you always have to include explicit normalization factors when calculating probabilities, therefore also another philosophy exists where the state vector is required to be normalized. Now normalization only fixes the absolute value of $c$ in the ray description above, not the phase factor $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\varphi}$. Therefore in this philosophy, the set of state vectors that describe the same state is the set you described; it is the intersection of a ray with the unit sphere.

However in my many years of doing quantum mechanics I've never seen that set to be called a ray. Rather in that form, one usually speaks of the free choice of phase.

Comment: You mean $\lambda\in\Bbb R_{\gt0}$, not $v\in\Bbb R_{\gt0}$?

Comment: @edm: Yes, I did (although as I actually wrote it it's not actually wrong; there's nothing stopping you to name a vector $\lambda$ and a positive real number $v$. It's counter-intuitive, though, so I'll fix it).

Comment: I think, Wikipedia is correct in the sense that its references support its definitions. Bäuerle & de Kerf's definitions are exaclty the same as Wikipedia's, while Weinberg's "ray" is identical with Wikipedia's "unit ray". But you are also correct in the sense that the original notion of Weyl (The theory of groups and Quantum Mechanics. London 1931, p. 4 and p. 20) is simply means a one-dimensional subspace. I don't understand your $\mathbb R_{>0}$. It defines a *cone*, doesn't is?  $\mathbb R^{\times}$ wouldn't be better?

Comment: @mma: I've edited the part about the Wikipedia article. On the $\mathbb R_{>0}$ part: To my knowledge, that's how rays are defined in real vector spaces (more generally, rays are half lines, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_%28mathematics%29#Ray)). And yes, a ray defined that way is a (very special) cone (but most cones are not rays).

Comment: Oh, now I see the correspondence The set $\{c\psi\mid c\in\mathbb C^\times\}$ can be written as $\{\mathbb T\lambda\psi$ $\mid \lambda\in\mathbb R_{>0}\}$ $\cong \mathbb T\times \mathcal R$ where $\mathcal R$  is a real ray.